# What is the best way to extract all rows from Datatables under a criteria in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatables

I'm currently working on a condominum program. The goal of this issue is when one Apartment row is clicked on the Parent table all the months - related to that apartment - must be displayed on the Child table.

The click/select/deselect is working fine but I can not obtain all the twelfth months.

This is my actual tables layout (example 1):
[image: Apartment 5C selected an only Janeiro (January) is displayed]

And this is my actual tables layout (example 2):
[image: Same thing with apartment 7A]

My code to childTable is:

```
var childTable = $('#child').DataTable( {
    "pageLength": 12,
    ajax: {
      url: "ajax/query_pagquotas.php",  // This is the URL to the server script for the child data
      dataSrc: function (data) {
        var selected = parentTable.row( { selected: true } );
        if ( selected.any() ) {
                var ID = selected.data().ID;
                for (var i=0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                    var rows = data.data[i];
                    if (rows.ID === ID) {
                    return [rows];
                    }
                }   
        } else {
        return [];
        }
    }
    },

    columns: [
        { "data": "ID" },
        { "data": "DATA" },
        { "data": "MES" },
        { "data": "VALOR" },
        { "data": "METODO" },
        { "data": "ESTADO" },
        { "data": "OBS" }

    ]
    
} );
```

Thanks for your help Masters

[edited]

Ups! If condition at the end does not make the 'deselect' work...

This is my full code at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parentTable = $('#parent').DataTable( {
        ajax: "ajax/dbfraccoes.php",
        "language": {
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Apto ou Proprietário...",
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Portuguese.json",
        },
        "processing": true,
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
        pageLength: 5,
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "ID","searchable": false },
            { "data": "APTO" },
            { "data": "FRACCAO"},
            { "data": "PROPRIETARIO" },
            { "data": "VALOR_QUOTA","searchable": false, className: "cssValores"},
            { "data": "OBS" }
        ]
    } );
  
  // tabela Child ------------------------------------------
          
    var childTable = $('#child').DataTable( {
           columnDefs: [{
           targets: 6,
           render: function(data, type, row, meta){
              if(type === 'display' && data === 'EMITIDO'){
                 data = '<td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm cssButton center" title="Emitido Aviso de Recibo a pagamento">EMITIDO</button></td>'+
                 '<div class="links">' +
                 '<a href="<?php echo WEB_URL;?>credit_debit/gest_quotas.php?spid='+row['pqid']+'#insert">Editar</a> ' +
                 '</div>';      
              }else if (type === 'display' && data === 'AGUARDA'){
                 data = '<td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm cssButton center" title="Limite de pagamento ultrapassado. Em período de tolerância.">AGUARDA</button></td>'+
                 '<div class="links">' +
                 '<a href="<?php echo WEB_URL;?>credit_debit/gest_quotas.php?spid='+
                 row['pqid']+'#insert">Editar</a> ' +
                 '</div>'; 
                  
              }  
               
              return data;
           }
        }],
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "language": {
        "zeroRecords": "<center>Clique na tabela acima, na linha do apartamento que pretende. <br/>Os dados da fracção/apartamento selecionado acima serão reflectidos nesta tabela</center>",
        },
    
        ajax: {
          url: "ajax/query_pagquotas.php",
          
          dataSrc: function (data) {
            var selected = parentTable.row( { selected: true } );
            if ( selected.any() ) {
                var rows = []; // create an empty array
                var ID = selected.data().ID;
                for (var i=0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        var row = data.data[i];
                        if (row.ID === ID) {
                        rows.push(row);     
                        }
                }
            }
            
            return rows;
        },
        },
    
        columns: [
            { "data": "pqid" },
            { "data": "ID"},
            { "data": "DATA" },
            { "data": "MES"},
            { "data": "VALOR", className: "cssValores"},
            { "data": "METODO" },
            { "data": "ESTADO" },
            { "data": "OBS" }
    
        ]
        
    } );

// This will load the child table with the corresponding data
parentTable.on( 'select', function () {
    childTable.ajax.reload();
} );  

//clear the child table
parentTable.on( 'deselect', function () {
    childTable.ajax.reload();
} );  
} );
```

Comment: What is the processing flow you are trying to implement here? When a user clicks on a parent row, what happens next? Do you want to send an ajax request to the server (`ajax/query_pagquotas.php`), together with the parent ID? And that returns the 12 rows you want to display in the child table? Or something different? Also: How have you implemented your parent table click/select/deselect?

Comment: Hi andrewjames, I appreciate your reply. The ajax request is indeed sent to the server, but the server only returns the first row. I think I messed up something with the for cycle. If I take out the for cycle ALL the data appears on the child table this is 12 months correctly stated times the Apartments. I do the click select with `select: { style: 'single',}` complemented with `parentTable.on( 'select', function () { childTable.ajax.reload();} );` for select and `parentTable.on( 'deselect', function () {childTable.ajax.reload();} );` for deselect.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the logic which sends the selected ID to the target URL. If you don't pass that ID to your PHP script, you can't assemble the correct 12 records to send back to the child DataTable. I cannot help you with the PHP code, but I can suggest how you can send the ID to the server. Do I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes andrew. Please do, this javascript rookie is hunger for learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to adjust your existing code, is to change the logic in your `dataSrc: function (data) {...}`.

At the moment, you are only creating an array of one item.

So, instead you can do this:

```js
dataSrc: function (data) {
  var selected = parentTable.row( { selected: true } );
  var rows = []; // create an empty array
  if ( selected.any() ) {
    var ID = selected.data().ID;
    for (var i=0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      var row = data.data[i]; // change the variable name to "row"
      if (row.ID === ID) {
        rows.push(row); // add the new row to your array of rows
      }
    }
  }
  return rows; // return your array of rows
}
```

The most important line here is: `rows.push(row);` which is how JavaScript adds a new item to the end of an array.

So, now at the end of your `dataSrc` function you will either have an empty array `[]` if no rows were selected, or you will have an array of rows which match your ID.

That should solve your current problem.

---

The above approach should work - but it involves fetching every child row, every time - and then filtering out the ones you do not want to show.

You can probably improve on this by submitting the ID of the selected row as part of the child table's ajax URL. You can move the relevant code from its current location into your parentTable's `on(select)` function:

```js
  var selectedID = -1

  parentTable.on( 'select', function () { 
    var selected = parentTable.row( { selected: true } );
    if ( selected.any() ) {
      selectedID = selected.data().ID;
    }
    childTable.ajax.reload();
  } );
```

I do not know how you have implemented your `ajax/query_pagquotas.php`, so I am not sure of the best way to pass the `selectedID` parameter to it.

Normally I would append it as a query parameter in your ajax parameters:

```
data: 'id=' + selectedID
```

You may already know how to do this yourself.

Once you have passed the `selectedID` to your PHP, then you can use it to return only the records you want to display - and you can remove all of the existing `dataSrc: function (data) {...}` logic from your child table definition.

Comment: Great help andrew! It works! All the months appears now. The only issue is that when I 'deselect' any row on parentTable the last data remain on the childTable. It must return nothing... what is the best way to achive this? Create a if condition at the end? Once again thank you for your help and very pedagogical answer.

Comment: That is interesting. If I use your code, `parentTable.on( 'deselect', function () {childTable.ajax.reload();} );`, then the child table is empty after I de-select my previously selected row. There was nothing else I needed to change in the code. I am not sure why you are seeing the previous data still there.  Can you edit the question to show the updated relevant parts of your code?

Comment: andrew, I edited it and place my full code at the moment.

Comment: Move your `var rows = [];` so it is before the `if ( selected.any() )` code block. I realize it's wrong in my answer! I will fix that. Sorry about that.

Comment: Now it works 100% fine. Thank you for your kind help. It was very enlightening.  A great "Obrigado" from Portugal!